# Formula that Returns "No Report' to Same field

Tags: sharepoint-online

I've got a SP List with a calculated field titled 'Date of Last Inspection'. This field is auto-populated by data from other columns in the same list. Some of the fields in the calculation of blank, leaving some of the fields in the 'Date of Last Inspection' blank. I've attempted to write a formula that will replace blank fields in the 'Date of Last Inspection' field with "No Report Submitted". My attempt return either syntax or circular reference error messages. Such as =IF(ISBLANK([Date of Last Inspection]),"No Report Submitted",[Date of Last Inspection]) - The formula contains a circular reference (the calculated column refers to itself). You must remove or change the circular reference.